# C# GSMcomm extract SMS when MessageReceived is triggered

Tags: c#, gsmcomm

Is there a way to extract the content of a newly received message and place it in a string variable when the MessageReceived event is triggered?

Comment: what do you need to extract those incoming message? store it to database or another? give me an explanation

Answer (score 0):

it's so simple just add method like this:

```
private void comm_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = e.IndicationObject;
    if (obj is MemoryLocation)
    {
        var loc = (MemoryLocation)obj;
        var msg = string.Format("New message received in storage \"{0}\", index {1}.",
                                loc.Storage, loc.Index);
        MessageBox.Show(msg);

        DecodedShortMessage[] messages = CommSetting.comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, PhoneStorageType.Sim);
        foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
        {
            DisplayMessage(message.Data);
        }
        return;
    }
}

private void DisplayMessage(SmsPdu pdu)
{
    if (pdu is SmsDeliverPdu)
    {
        SmsDeliverPdu data = (SmsDeliverPdu)pdu;
        var phoneNumber = data.OriginatingAddress; 
        var msg = data.UserDataText;
        var date = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", data.SCTimestamp.ToDateTime());
        var time = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", data.SCTimestamp.ToDateTime());

        //read message in listBox1
        listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", date, time, phoneNumber, msg));
    }
}
```

but don't forget register this event when connection is open:

```
comm.MessageReceived += new MessageReceivedEventHandler(comm_MessageReceived);
```

i hope this help :D

Comment: Tried to implement this..
What is "CommSetting" here? It is showing me error

Comment: `CommSetting` is class for setup connection to gsm comm library. go to this link and download sample project [link](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm)

Comment: `class CommSetting
    {
        public static string Comm_Port = "";
        public static Int64 Comm_BaudRate = 0;
        public static Int64 Comm_TimeOut = 0;
        public static GsmCommMain comm;

        public CommSetting()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        } 
    }`